# Add XML to dictionary containing array C#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

```
<status_code>0</status_code>
<status_msg>Success</status_msg> 
<customer_details>
<customer_id>1</customer_id>
<number>99884522</number>
<mobile_number>4562214555</mobile_number>
<customer_name>Test </customer_name>
<balance>457.67</balance>
</customer_details>

</xml>
```

I want to add the xml code to dictionary, how can I do it? I want the `customer_details` array to contain the details too.

So far, I tried

```
            var webResponse = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlfile);// ("filename.xml"); 

            foreach (XElement el in xDoc.Root.Elements())
            {
                if (el.HasElements)
                {
                    webResponse.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);
                }
                webResponse.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);

            }
```

I want Output int the form of Json or within the dictionary

```
{
    "status_code": 0,
    "status_msg": "Success",

    "customer_details": {
    "customer_id": "1",
    "number": "24234234",
    "mobile_number": "24423423432", 
    "customer_name": "Test ",
    "balance": "467.67"
}
```

}

Comment: Has your customer_details xml element a defined structure? if so, you could go for serialization...

Comment: Currently your `if (el.HasElements)` body is exactly the same as the statement following it. That's probably not what you intended. Could you maybe just use `Descendants()` rather than `Elements()`? If you could show what your expected output is (along with your current output) that would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft Json.

```
 XDocument X = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\XMLFile.xml");
 var elements =   X.Elements("xml"); 
     foreach (var item in elements)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(item);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
```

The Output

```
   {
"xml": {
    "status_code": "0",
    "status_msg": "Success",
    "customer_details": {
        "customer_id": "1",
        "number": "99884522",
        "mobile_number": "4562214555",
        "customer_name": "Test ",
        "balance": "457.67"
    }
}
}
```

The XML used was

```
 <xml>
<status_code>0</status_code>
<status_msg>Success</status_msg>
<customer_details>
  <customer_id>1</customer_id>
  <number>99884522</number>
  <mobile_number>4562214555</mobile_number>
  <customer_name>Test </customer_name>
  <balance>457.67</balance>
</customer_details>
</xml>
```